# How to speed up nagios to monitor hosts over the cloud

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, nagios, nrpe

while using nagios with multiple hosts spread over the network,hosts status shows a recognizable lag and takes a long time to reflect on nagios server cgi.Thus what  is the optimal nrpe/nagios configration to speed up the status process for a distributed host environment.
In my case I use nagios core 4.1
nrpe 1.5
server/clients: Amazon ec2

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is usually only updated once each minute (automatically), though clicking refresh can provide you with 'nearly' the latest information.  I say nearly because there is a distinct processing loop inside of the Nagios core that causes it to never be real time.  NRPE is going to run at the speed of your network connection - it does little else besides sending and receiving tiny amounts of data.  About the only delay here is the time it takes to actually perform the check and send back the response - which, of course, has way to many factors to mention.  Try looking at the output of

```
[nagioshome]/bin/nagiostats
```

There are several entries that tell you:

```
'Latency' - the time between when the check was scheduled to start, and the actual start time.

'Execution Time' - the amount of time checks are actually taking to run.
```

These entries will have three numbers, which are; Min / Max / Avg

**High latency numbers** (in my book that means Avg is greater than 1 second) usually means your Nagios server is over worked.  There are a few things you can do to improve latency times, and these are outlined in the 'nagios.cfg' file.  This latency has nothing to do with network speed or the speed of NRPE - it is primarily hardware speed.  If you're already using the optimal values specified in nagios.cfg, then its time to find some faster hardware.

**High execution times** (for me an Avg greater than 5 seconds) can be blamed on just about everything **except your Nagios system.**  This can be caused by faulty networks (improper packet routing), over loaded networks, faulty and/or poorly designed checks, slow target systems, ... the list is endless.  Nothing you do with the Nagios and/or NRPE configs will help lower these values.  Well, you could disable NRPE's encryption to improve wire time; but if you have encryption enabled in the first place, then its not likely you'd want it disabled.